# How to combine two complex Dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift

I'm curious how to combine two dictionaries which one of them contains key with array or another dictionary as value.

for simple combining e.g.

```
    var dict1 = ["bbb":"dict1",
                 "her": "dict1"]

    let dict2 = ["aaa":"dict2",
                 "her": "doct2",
                 "bob": "doct2"]

    dict1 += dict2 // result is as I expected


    func += <K, V> (inout left: [K:V], right: [K:V]) {
        for (k, v) in right {
            left.updateValue(v, forKey: k)
        }
    }
```

But problem rise when I want to combine more complex dictionary e.g.

```
var dict1 = ["bbb":"dict1",
             "her": "dict1"]


let complexDict2 = ["aaa":"dict2",
                    "her": "dict2",
                    "arr": ["one", "two"]]


dict1 += complexDict2 // in here method which override '+=' operator for dictionaries does not work anymore...
```

My question is whether you guys have a proved way to combine more complex dictionaries?

**Upadate**

My expected result from combining dict1 and complexDict2 is :

```
let resultDict    = ["aaa":"dict1",
                    "aaa":"dict2",
                    "her": "dict2",
                    "arr": ["one", "two"]]
```

Comment: What is your desired result, and how does it differ from the actual result?

Comment: Nearly every time I've seen a dictionary of dictionaries, it's been some horrific shit-show that should be using nested structs. I'd be cautious with this.

Comment: Note that this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). One major missing component is that you must have `import Foundation` for `complexDict` to have the inferred type `[String : NSObject]`, otherwise it results in an error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". In general it's good to stage your code in a playground and see if it works, then post the code from the playground verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here lies in the types of `dict1` and `complexDict2`.

`dict1` is inferred to have type `[String : String]`, whereas `complexDict2` is inferred to have type `[String : Any]`.

Your code works just fine, if you explicitly specify a type annotation on `dict1`:

```
var dict1: [String : Any] = [
    "aaa":"dict1",
    "her": "dict1"
]
```

Comment: I thought that should work but got an error of "fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes" when trying it in a playground.  However, `[String : AnyObject]` works fine.  I haven't figured out why the "Any" error happens. (Xcode 7.3.1)

Comment: That's odd. May I ask why you're doing this, in the first place?

Comment: Me?  I was trying to verify what I thought was an answer to the question.  :)

Comment: Oh, I confused you for OP.

Comment: @PhillipMills Interesting, it seems to work just fine here: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57acc52f603420ce5f482bb4

Comment: The difference is that you also specify the type for `complexDict2`.  I was allowing it to be inferred and only specifying for `dict1`.  What was inferred in my playground (oddly!) was `[String:NSObject]`, which appears to match AnyObject but not Any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120730/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-phillip-mills).